# Unable to click on Chinese linkText on Salesforce Chinese version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

All I am trying to go to Chinese sales force . and click on the products `linkbyText` using UTF. How do I do it? When I do via my method I get an exception.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.salesforce.com/cn/");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("\ufeff\u89e3\u51b3\u65b9\u6848")).click();
System.out.println("finish");
```

Error Message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"解决方案"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 1.08 seconds For documentation on this
>   error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly fine if I use Chinese characters directly in the string.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("解决方案")).click();
```

Or use XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='解决方案']")).click();
```

However, the best would be matching `href` attribute instead of text.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@href='/cn/solutions/']")).click(); // XPath version
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/cn/solutions/']")).click(); // CSS selector version
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a common misconception that linktext method used href value to look for an element. Rather it needs just the text part of the link that is visible which in your case is chinese text.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("解决方案")).click();
```

In case some part of it is varible, you can use By.PartialLinkText method passing the constant part of the link text as parameter

Comment: Just in case you didn't know. OP's `\ufeff\u89e3\u51b3\u65b9\u6848` is `解决方案`, which is the text, not the href in the first place.

Comment: Didn't knew that. Just checked that using google translator. Thanks